# Passing redux state to component on page load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a react-redux app where in my root component (`route "/"`) a GET request to my rails API is made inside `componentDidMount()` to fetch some data. This data is added in the redux store and the state is passed between components accordingly.

Now, I have a component that gets its props from the root component to render properly. This component has a specific route that the user can navigate to. Now, if a user sent this route to one of their friends and they typed it in the browser, it would not render because the root component was never rendered on their end as they never navigated "/", and therefore the props would not be available.

Is there a way to fix this? Perhaps I can have a conditional inside the render method of this component to make a GET request from my rails API, or I can add the API call to the constructor? But I feel that is bad practice. I cannot add this inside of `componentDidMount()` because `render()` gets executed before `componentDidMount()`.

Hopefully this makes sense, and I appreciate any help!

Comment: If this data is required on every page, then I would look at moving it outside of the router and calling it as part of mounting your main app component. Another option is if the data is always required you could look at adding templating fields to your html page and replace these with the data you want to load while serving the html page, this way the data is present on the page from the get go. I would not know how to go about doing this with ruby-on-rails, but it is relatively easy to do in C#.

Comment: Sorry for this late response, but I felt this approach was most logical. I simply moved my API calls outside of the router and mounted to the main app component. It prevents code duplication.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the redux state is empty. If it is empty, you fetch the data from the server. To avoid code duplication you should implement this in a HOC (Higer-order-component). Then you can wrap the page with the HOC.

you can check how to implement a HOC in the React docs:
https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Where do you suggest I check if the redux state is empty? Inside of componentDidMount() or inside render()?

Comment: inside the componentDidMount() of the HOC component